# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object not found However, the object does appear to exist

Tags: r, lm

I am new to R and to actually asking a question in Stack Overflow.  I looked at several similar questions, but they did not seem to apply to help my situation.  I am trying to make a linear model with the lm() function, but I get an error returned that states one of my data frame columns is able to be found:

```
library(SemiPar) # Contains Janka data

data(janka)
names(janka) <- c("Density", "Hardness")

janka.ls1 <- lm(hardness~dens, Data = janka)
```

I get the following error after running the final line:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Hardness' not found
```

As you can see, I named one of the two columns 'Hardness' and when I view the data I also see that the names do match.  Further,  when I try running the code using the original data column name, it still has the same issue.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You've renamed the column name `hardness` to `Hardness`, but then use the old name `hardness` in your `lm` model. Ditto for `dens`. So you need to do `lm(Hardness ~ Density, data = janka)`. Vote to close as simple typo.

Comment: R is case sensitiive. In addition to the problem already discssed in the last comment the code in the question uses `Data = ` whereas what is needed is `data = ` .

Comment: Hello.  Thanks to both of you.  I actually added a comment stating that I realized that it was because of the capitalization of `Data= ` (I copied the wrong line from my code, I did actually use `Hardness` and `Density`.  For some reason, someone deleted my comment that explained my error.  Not sure why they did that.  Thanks for your help!  I also vote to close.